# Does a sotah warning from a couples first marriage carry into their second marriage?

Tags: women, marriage, divorce, sotah-secluded-woman

If a husband warns his wife not to be secluded with a certain man ("sotah warning") and subsequently divorces and remarries the same woman does the initial sotah warning carry over into the second marriage such that if the woman is secluded with the designated man she can become a sotah?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Rambam (Hil. Sotah 1:7) rules that divorce erases the previous warning and if they remarry, he would have to warn again. Kesef Mishneh notes that the source is the Yerushalmi in the second chapter of Sotah.

Answer (score 6):

He'd need a new warning. (Rambam [Sotah 1:7](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=4&hilchos=26&perek=1&halocha=7&hilite=), Shulchan Arukh [EH 178:12](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%91%D7%9F_%D7%94%D7%A2%D7%96%D7%A8_%D7%A7%D7%A2%D7%97_%D7%99%D7%91))